# Declare datetime as UTC?

Tags: c#, datetime, npgsql

I currently have a issue where I want to store a datetime range but cannot specify its kind to be UTC.

```
        Valid = dapperRow["valid"] as NpgsqlRange<DateTime>?;
```

How can I unsure that the input is passed into an UTC formatted Datetime?

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry about which timezone input is in. While using the value use UTC time format.

```
localDateTime = DateTime.Parse(strDateTime);
univDateTime = localDateTime.ToUniversalTime();
```

Comment: I need it to be declared as UTC and after convert it to UTC